# Service Layer Validation for Razor Pages

Tags: .net, validation, dependency-injection, razor-pages, clean-architecture

I have a .net web application using a razor pages. I have a "Services" like studentService, and I have "Repositories" like studentRepository. The StudentService is in the Application layer and the StudentRepository is in the Domain layer. I have razor pages in the webpresentation layer.

I am using dependency injection:

`servicesCollection.AddScoped<IStudentService, StudentService>(); servicesCollection.AddScoped<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();`

The problem is I want to implement certain validation logic in StudentService.

I have been using this as a guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

The issue is the Guide was written for MVC. The problem in that guide is that the ValidationLogic makes use of the ModelState, which is passed into the StudentService's constructor. This is fine because the StudentService would usually be instantiated in the StudentController, where the ModelState would be passed to the StudentService constructor.

But in my case, for Razor Pages, I am not instantiating the StudentService. I am injecting it.
How should I get the ModelState into the service? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: My opinion:  input validation (which is what `ModelState` is all about) should be done in the controller/PageModel class as close to the UI as possible. You should only pass valid objects to your service layer.

Comment: @Mike Brind Thank you ! Do you have recommended pattern or where I can find about how to enforce business rules/logic ?  Like validation, but for logic. Like one value has to be greater than another in order for purchase to be made.

Comment: `IValidatableObject` is very commonly used and can solve many problems easily and cleanly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ivalidatableobject

Comment: If you want to validate two attributes,you can try to use [PageRemote attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.remoteattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0).